# Ajax form in response of ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a problem:

I make ajax query to the database and display information about a specific ID and displays it in HTML-formatted message return.

**Here's the HTML code:**

```
<!-- WINE -->
<div id="slides">
    <div id="information_slide" class="slide">
        <!-- container as a result of JS -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- WINE -->

<!-- LOADING -->
<div id="loading_slide" class="slide" style="display: none;">
    Loading information about the wine ...<br/><br/><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<!-- LOADING -->

<!-- AJAX CALL BUTTON -->
<?php
    echo '<div id="'.$id['id'].'" class="menuItem">Show wine when ID = '.$id['id'].'</div>';
?>
<!-- AJAX CALL BUTTON -->
```

**Here's the JS code:**

[JavaScript]

```
$('.menuItem').on('click', function() {

    // ID Wine
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'function.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#slides #information_slide').fadeOut(200, function() {
                $('#slides #loading_slide').fadeIn(200);
            });
        },
        data: {
            funkcja: 'show_wine',
            id: id
            },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#slides #loading_slide').fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $('#slides #information_slide').html(result).fadeIn(400);
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    // alert(id);
});
```

[/JavaScript]

**Here's the PHP code:**

[php]

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['funkcja']) && !empty($_POST['funkcja'])) {
        switch($_POST['funkcja']) {
            case 'show_wine':
                show_wine($_POST['id']);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Callback wine function
    function show_wine($id) {

        $qwerty = "SELECT * FROM `wina` WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1";
        $sql = mysql_query($qwerty);

        while($id = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            echo '
                <div id="'.$id['id'].'" class="element">
                    <form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="'.$_SESSION['jcartToken'].'" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="'.$id['id'].'" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="'.stripslashes($id['nazwa']).'" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="'.stripslashes($cena_przecinek).'" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" class="item-sztuk" />

                            <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="to cart" class="item-button" />

                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                    <!-- ... remaining HTML code... -->

                </div>
            ';
        }

    }
?>
```

[/php]

I have a result as previously described.
The script shows me the information (records) a specific ID from the database - this part of the script is OK.

The problem I have at the moment when the PHP callback function (which is called Ajax) hosts a form uses also Ajax functions.
This part of HTML code in response from PHP function...

```
<form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="'.$_SESSION['jcartToken'].'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="'.$id['id'].'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="'.stripslashes($id['nazwa']).'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="'.stripslashes($cena_przecinek).'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" class="item-sztuk" />

        <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="to cart" class="item-button" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

... is form of my jCart script. Button (name=my-add-button) not work.

JS script is loaded from the very beginning on page:

[html]

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="files/jcart.js"></script>
</head>
```

[/html]

When i call a ajax function, load a result (html code) to the container and button with should add item to cart, page is reloading and item only is added to cart.
I've tried to add **return false;** in a PHP script, but if there happens to be absolutely nothing.

Here is the JS code file jcart -> [www.starwines.com.pl/jcart/js/jcart.js](http://starwines.com.pl/jcart/js/jcart.js)

AND here is DEMO PAGE -> [www.starwines.com.pl/test.php](http://starwines.com.pl/test.php)

**Please try the following:**
**1)** add an item by clicking the "**Dodaj do koszyka**" (yellow button)
**2)** select a different wine from the carousel, and then click "Dodaj do koszyka"

How to solve this problem?

Regards !

PS. Sorry for English language, I'm weak :)

Comment: are these 2 php snippets in separate files?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. There is one file. The form is where the pointed commentary <!-- HTML code --> in first PHP code.

Comment: i don't believe you can/should echo multiple response in one ajax call

Comment: I corrected description of the problem, please re-read

Comment: so the `form` where the `button` in it not working is returned by php code? when/how do you send ajax call to get the form?

Comment: when i click <div id="X" class="menuItem">Show wine when ID = X</div> is executed Ajax script. In response i have HTML code AND form who also is executed another ajax script - that should add item to my cart. This not work. Here is the JS code file jcart -> www.starwines.com.pl/jcart/js/jcart.js AND here is DEMO PAGE -> www.starwines.com.pl/test.php try the following: 1) add an item by clicking the "Dodaj do koszyka" (yellow button) 2) select a different wine from the carousel, and then click "Dodaj do koszyka". Here is my problem

Comment: so what you want to achieve here is when user select different item and click that button, it should behave like the first time they click, item being added to cart?

Comment: exactly! After performing reloading button has to work the same

Comment: where do you bind `.item-button` click event? after choosing another wine, there is no click event binding to that button, so you form will be posted and your page will be freshed. Thus you can bind event using `$(document).on('click', '.item-button', your_handler)`, this line of code will work even you add elements dynamically.

Comment: hmm.. u talking about line 174 from jcart.js ? -> http://starwines.com.pl/jcart/js/jcart.js

Comment: sorry for timezone issue, answer provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your click event binding code from

```
$('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
    add($(this));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('submit', '.jcart', function(e) {
    add($(this));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

will do the work.

[jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)